# How to start faye server on a rails app deployed using dokku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye, digital-ocean, dokku

I've hosted my rails application on Digitalocean using Dokku. There's this need for my application to run real-time applications through Faye. I've been trying several ways like the shoreman plugin for Dokku and adding `faye: bundle exec rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production` to "Procfile" file. But no luck till now, need help on how I can get this Faye server running for my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make several steps to have working faye server (e.g. on port 9292):

1. Your Procfile is OK
2. Expose port 9292 on Docker. I recommend install `docker-options` plugin and next `dokku docker-options:add timer "-p 9292:9292"`
3. Setup your app nginx.conf. Mine is here:

   ```
   upstream app { server 127.0.0.1:49154; }
     server {
     listen      [::]:80;
     listen      80;
     server_name app.dokku.mine;
     location    / {
       proxy_pass  http://app;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
       proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
   }
     location /faye {
       proxy_redirect     off;
       proxy_set_header   Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_buffering    off;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
       proxy_no_cache     $http_pragma $http_authorization;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;
     }
   }
   ```

I suggest to install `nginx-alt` plugin because config is overwritten on every deploy.